# Java распределение запросов

Tags: java, android

Стакчане здраствуйте.Написал сервис  rest.поступает около 2000 запросов в день.Не много но всеже .И так суть вопроса все эти запросв поступают на 1 сервис .могу ли я на сервере задеплоить еще один экзпмпляр такого сервиса.Как распределить запросы?в какую сторону идти?не уверен что смоо донести мысль.Но кто понел прошу четко жать понять что надо куда идти какая это сфера

Comment: На том же сервере не смысла деплоить еще один сервис, т.к. нагрузку на аппаратные ресурсы это не уменьшит.

Comment: @a_gura a wto delat?

Comment: нужен 2ой сервер и балансировщик запросов перед ними

Comment: @Nikolay а можно поподробнее о балансиировщике ?кто это что это

Comment: @elik это сервер, отвечающий за балансировку (распределение) запросов между backend-серверами. почитайте в интернете более подробно

Comment: Например, вы можете поднять nginx, который будет раскидывать запросы на группу java-серверов.